# PXE Boot not working

Tags: windows, networking, pxe

Please explain the error in this screenshot:

[image]

DHCP Setting:

[image]

This screenshot was taken after powering off the old comp hence the server interface is shown as the wireless card - it becomes 192.168.0.1 when I connect wires and power up the old laptop to boot via PXE.

My scenario is simple. An old laptop and a new laptop . A cross over cable ( that I myself made from CAT 6 cable by cutting it and connecting 4 wires as mentioned in some doc).
The new laptop ( tftp server ) has a Wirelss Card ( with which I am browsing and writing this ) . And the cable is connected between laptops .

TFTP server ( new laptop details )

Windows IP Configuration

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f511:3d4a:ca01:122e%16
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Achilles
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::99b1:8ae0:9e6c:f300%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem. Things to keep in mind:

1. Use crossover cable - not the usual LAN wire - router connections use this type of cable
2. Assign an IP after connecting the computers and make sure the subnet mentioned matches
3. You need the ISO in an Apache webserver - you can extract the ISO to a folder and provide the folder name during PXE booting to install

Comment: You do not need to use a crossover cable as long as at least one of the NICs is a gigabit rated one, as they can auto-sense as port of the specification. Also, if you have Windows Server, using Windows Deployment Services is easier and neater, in my opinion (as there is no need to fiddle about with cables and network settings), although you would need to extract the Windowds disc/iso to a .wim file.